# How to change Roles permission to another CrudController

Tags: laravel, crud, laravel-backpack

[Roles Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9tXs.png)

I would like to change the Roles Permission in another CrudController into which is i want to put it in the DepartmentCrudController. It is below the Kepala Department and as i highlighted in red colour. Is there any possible way to do it ?

[Department Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIJ3d.png)

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

class Department extends Model
{
    use CrudTrait;
    use HasRoles;
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | GLOBAL VARIABLES
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
CONST ROLE_SCURITY = "Scurity";
CONST ROLE_PENJAGA_MALAM = "Penjaga Malam";

protected $table = 'departments';
// protected $primaryKey = 'id';
// public $timestamps = false;
protected $guarded = ['id'];
// protected $fillable = [];
// protected $hidden = [];
// protected $dates = [];

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| FUNCTIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RELATIONS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
public function headOfDepartment(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','department_head');
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| SCOPES
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| ACCESSORS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| MUTATORS
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
```

}

Comment: We don't care about views. Show us controllers and make yourself clear what exactly you need? Call controller from controller?

Comment: I have inserted the code for department however i would like to change the roles from backpack/permissionmanager roles crud controller in the departmentcrudcontroller

Comment: It is always better to offload your logic from controller to service class. And call this class wherever you want with dependency injection